# TDAPIOLE80 issue with test item number

Tags: testing, qtp, hp-uft, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I am new user to QTP+ALM and i am struggling to understand the usage of Item number with TestFactory. I have managed to read number of articles on this site and it seems, it is a unique id and hence is used by the code that i have inherited. Specifically the code below:

```
set tdc = CreateObject("tdapiole80.tdconnection")
set testfact = tdc.TestFactory
mytest = testFact.Item(par_Test_ID)
```

I have noticed that "par_test_ID" is a unique value in all the QTP scripts, and is being used to copy the script into the Datatable Action1.

Now if i create a new script, where would i get this number from. I have tried looking in the details in test lab and test plan. However can't find this particular number anywhere. I do see that there is some ID number mentioned, however it's just different number to the one being used.

Comment: The parameter for item is same as index, starts from 0 to n.

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots and example numbers that you are seeing for par_Test_ID and the numbers that you are seeing in the details of test lab and test plan?

Comment: Thanks Barney & dmcgill50. I figured out that the suite being old, these test ID's were still coming from archived regression suite, instead of the one being current. Hence the reason for missing them. Though i still don't see any utility of copying the manual test steps over into the datatable so far(There is no use of this data so far in the code), unless it helps with debugging?